# Small chunks from brush in paint

Tags: wood, paint

So I took it upon myself to paint some wood endcaps (very small, about 8 inches long) from their sealed wood color to white. I sanded down the wood, wiped with a damp cloth, then applied a coat of white paint/primer mix.

Well, painting isn't my forte and I didn't clean the brush between coats. Bad melee. I used paint thinner to try to clean the brush, as well as hot water - I thought I did a pretty good job, until I went to paint the second coat - now there's small chunks of paint in the finish.

Do I need to sand an start over again, or can this be saved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you have to redo the whole thing.

You are a brave soul for admitting what you did.  I think I would have just redone it before anyone found out, especially my wife.

You might try just getting a new brush and doing your second coat.  It could cover up the chunks, or you could end up with two coats to sand back off.  If the latter, I would keep it silent.

Comment: Haha, thanks? I'm learning. I think it is ok to mess up a few times :)

Comment: Of course it is.  I screw up A LOT!  It is still funny.  I am glad you shared.

Comment: So it has two coats on it right now - do I just need to go crazy with the sanding pad and take it down to the original color, then just do another two coats?

Comment: I am not a painting pro.  I think with decorative wood the best way is usually paint thinner.  If it does not have too much detail then put another CLEAN coat on it.  There is a plethora of options here.  Sanding is just one of them.

Comment: Uh oh. Options. This is not good, haha

Comment: What kind of paint did you use?  latex or oil based?  I keep seeing the word "thinner" used. Thinner or mineral spirits should only be used with oil based paints, not latex.  BTW, do sand the boo boo down until it is smooth again, even if that means going back to bare wood.